# Call a specific activity for In-app message after MainActivity has been launched and not in the SplashActivity

Tags: android, in-app, android-inapp-purchase

I have a service that handles the incoming in-app message. The app has a SplashActivity, MainActivity and a second Activity which is called to display this in-app message from the Service.
The in-app is getting displayed in the SplashActivity if the mainActivity takes a longer time to launch. How do I ensure that the in-app message activity(which is initiated by the service) is called only after the MainActivity is being displayed to the user.

I saw a similar issue in [Firebase In-App Messaging showing in SplashActivity. How to show it in MainActivity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57957739/firebase-in-app-messaging-showing-in-splashactivity-how-to-show-it-in-mainactiv), but I have my own implementation of the in-app message handling.

Comment: You can give a try for https://www.apxor.com/ to show In-app messages and many more actions contextually at runtime

Comment: As mentioned, I have my own implementation for the in-app message handling. I cannot use a 3rd party SDK/Library.

Comment: could you share your code

Comment: What's the problem with launching the  in-app message activity inside `onResume` method of the MainActivity?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I ensure that the in-app message activity(which is initiated by
> the service) is called only after the MainActivity is being displayed
> to the user.

You should wait for your activity views to lay out and then display your message, to do that you can add a global layout listener to view tree observer of one of your activity views:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.some_view_id);

        view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                // Display your in-app message here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But from the sample code you specified, this would be triggered only once the MainActivity is called. But in my case since there is a service which is responsible to display the In-App message activity that would already have started running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem can be avoided by not devoting an activity to your `splashscreen` but rather doing your `splashscreen` the "[right way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60124091/10637400)" here is a link on the article on [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/the-complete-android-splash-screen-guide-c7db82bce565). this implies simply using your splash screen in the background of your main activity while it loads.

Comment: As per the link shared, I do need a dedicated SplashScreen Activity since I need to route to different screens based on some logic.  So in my case, I use the Method 2 of the link for a SplashScreen scenario.